# How to remove xml tags before send to the json parser in swift

Tags: ios, json, xml, swift

I want to use **JSON** data in my app. So I am using this webservice calling method to convert my json data to an array.

```
func getData(path: String, completion: (dataArray: NSArray)->()) {
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    // var datalistArray = NSArray()
    let baseUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!["BaseURL"] as! String
    let fullUrl = "\(baseUrl)\(path)"

    print("FULL URL-----HTTPClient \(fullUrl)")
    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string:fullUrl) else {
        print("Error creating endpoint")
        return
    }
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: endpoint)
    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request,completionHandler: {(data,response,error) in
        do {
            guard let data = data else {
                throw JSONError.NoData
            }
            guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSArray else {//NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments
                throw JSONError.ConversionFailed
            }
            print(json)
            if let data_list:NSArray = json {

                completion(dataArray: data_list)
                dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);


            }

        }catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }





    }) .resume()

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


}
```

But now my service sending json data within xml tags like `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">json data</string` so I am getting an exception when I try to convert my json data. The exception is this.

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

What should I change in my code to remove those tags before sending to json parser?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your response that you get from server is in `xml` format not in `json`. If it is in `xml` format then you must do `xml parsing` instead of json parsing.

`NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData` is json parsing that give json object from data (data in json format).

But if you getting response in xml format from server then you should use [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/) to parse the data.

If you don't have much idea about it then you can refer tutorial like 
[XML Parsing using NSXMLParse in Swift by The appguruz](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/xml-parsing-using-nsxmlparse-swift) or can use third party libraries.